# How to control behavior of command storage for macro repeat?

Tags: keyboard-macros

There are some actions which I would like to repeat however repeating the action doesn't work as I would like it to.

Take dabbrev, if I repeat a dabbrev completion, the result may be different based on the location I'm editing in the buffer.

So in this case I would like repeating the last action to simulate inserting the text (verbatim) that dabbrev inserted while recording the macro, instead of re-running dabbrev completion.

Is it possible to store the text entered as part of a function for the purpose of repeating an action ... instead of running that action (which may give unexpected results?).

---

Note, that a hack around this could be to get emacs to simulate keys being pressed by the operating system - this could work but wouldn't be very portable and is something I'd rather avoid. Possibly simulating key presses in Emacs it's self could work but this still seems like an awkward hack if there are better alternatives.

---

##### Test case:

Given this function & shortcut:

```el
(defun timestamp ()
  (interactive)
  (insert (format-time-string "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")))

(global-set-key (kbd "<f12>") 'timestamp)
```

I would like to be able to repeat `timestamp` and have it insert the time that was inserted when I ran the command (instead of the current time).

This is just to illustrate the functionality I'm looking for, the use-case for `dabbrev` is more compelling but more complicated to setup.

---

##### Real World Use Case:

Including this since it might seem as if this is obscure functionality, I'm using the package [fancy-dabbrev](https://github.com/jrosdahl/fancy-dabbrev) (although as far as I can see this would might to dabbrev too).

As I type, completion is shown which is very nice, with a key-shortcut I can complete the word. However, whenever I'm recording a macro or performing an action I need to repeat, I have to manually type in the text I can see on-screen (which could be completed), because I can't rely on this text being typed in when repeating the macro.
It's quite annoying and makes `fancy-dabbrev` less useful. Basically I would like the auto-complete function to behave as if I had typed the text, but the way emacs works seems to conflict with this.

Comment: The question isn't clear to me. Can you provide a recipe, to show what you mean?

Comment: Added example test case as well as details on the real world use-case (so the motivation for asking this is more clear)